# MongoDB - Update field with reference of another document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like if is possible to update a field of all documents in a collection with a reference to another document. I have tried to do this with the code below:

```
var project = db.Project.find({slug:"engine"});

db.Activity.update({}, {$set:{'project':DBRef("Project", project._id, "mydb")}});
```

When I look at the Activity documents, in the "project" field, the result is:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
  "project": DBRef("Project", undefined, "mydb")
}
```

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The purpose of NoSQL databases (MongoDB) is to have no relations between collections, databases or documents.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AnnaJeanine. I know that it is not the purpose, but I need to do this for reasons beyond my control.

Comment: Ok. Do you want to reference to a single document? Because in the query you may have gotten multiple values in `var project`

Comment: Yes, I want to reference to a single document, and the query 'db.Project.find({slug:"engine"})' returns only one document.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're having a promise callback problem. You can solve it in two ways:

Option one: Put the function depending of your data return inside a callback of the first function, for example:

```
db.Project.find({slug:"engine"}, function(error, data) {
    db.activity.update(...data.Id...);
});
```

Option two: Wait for the return of the find to be completed:

```
var project = db.Project.find({slug:"engine"});

project.then(function(error,data) {
       db.activity.update(...project.Id...);
});
```

Both should work. The problem is that when you make the first call, it returns a promise, not the value itself. If you are making confusion on this topic, you can take a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Hope my answer helped you.